# Why does [:1] work in a for loop but not [0] in python?

Tags: python, tuples

I just had a quick question about the difference between [:1] and [0]

The following program parses a text document and puts all instances of email addresses in said txt document in a dictionary, and then creates a list of tuples from this dictionary, then sorts the list and prints out the email with the most instances. Please read the last 2 lines of code on this program:

```
emails = dict()
fname = input('Enter file name: ')
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print("sorry can't do that")
    quit()
for line in fhand:
    if not line.startswith("From "):
        continue
    line = line.split()
    emails[line[1]] = emails.get(line[1], 0) + 1
tmp = list()
for k, v in emails.items():
    newtup = (v, k)
    tmp.append(newtup)
tmp = sorted(tmp, reverse = True)
for v, k in tmp[:1]:
    print(k, v)
```

Specifically, the last 2 lines of this program:

```
for v, k in tmp[:1]:
        print(k, v)
```

Works perfectly. But when I tried to do the same thing with this syntax:

```
for v, k in tmp[0]:
        print(k, v)
```

I get the following traceback:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I guess that `[0]` is in some way, not the same as `[:1]`? Why does `tmp[:1]` work but `tmp[0]` doesn't in a for loop?

I have no complaints since my program is running perfectly with the `tmp[:1]` syntax, but why doesn't it work with the `tmp[0]` syntax? Are they not the same thing?

Thanks for your time and for reading this if you've come this far!

Comment: `Are they not the same thing?` have you printed them and looked at the values?

Comment: "I guess that [0] is in some way, not the same as [:1]" **did you try and see what they actually do?

Comment: As an aside, just use `max`, you don't have to sort the entire list.

Comment: `list[0]` is the first element of the list and has the object class of the object you stored in this position. It may be an integer, string, or any other type. If it is not iterable, you can't iterate over it. `list[:1]` is a list of length 1, which contains only the first element of the list. Since it is still a list, you can iterate over it (for exactly one loop).

Comment: @the23Effect. Yes. Or if it contains a string or tuple at the first index. But it will iterate over that object, which may result in more than 1 loop.

Comment: Yeap, I deleted my post as you were right and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Emmm, here is an example.

```py
>> tmp = [1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                                                    
>> tmp[:1]                                                                                                                                                                                            
[1]
>> tmp[0]                                                                                                                                                                                             
1
>> type([1])                                                                                                                                                                                          
list
>> type(1)                                                                                                                                                                                            
int
```

As you see, `[:1]` and `[0]` produces different stuff. `[:1]` makes list, `[0]` returns first element. Why you didn't try it just yourself?

Also made an example just for you :)

```
>> tmp = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]

>> tmp[:1]
[(1, 1)]

>> tmp[0]
(1, 1)

>> for k,v in [(1, 1)]: pass

>> for k,v in (1, 1): pass
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Iteration like this does not make sence at all: `for k,v in (1, 1):`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about Python list indexing and slicing, as that is the difference between the two.

**tmp[:1]:**
This is list slicing syntax. This general form of this syntax is like this,

```
list_object[start_idx: end_index]
```

This returns a sliced list with elements starting from(including) start_idx and ending with end_idx(not inclusive, so one less than this value).

So in your question tmp[:1] returns a sublist(which is considered an **iterable**) with elements at 0. Since this is an iterable it is acceptable to iterate over in a for loop.

**tmp[0]:**
This is list indexing syntax. The general form is,

```
list_object[element_idex]
```

This returns an element at that index. The returned value may/may not be an iterable (it depends on what the list is composed of). In your case, tmp[0] returns the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Makes sense.

```
>>> tmp = [1, 2, 3]
>>> tmp[0]
1
>>> tmp[:1]
[1]
```

where tmp[0] could be any object, like something that can't be iterated through, like in my case, a tuple.